# Whitespace as an argument of a ksh script

Tags: linux, escaping, whitespace, ksh

Suppose you have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

for element in $@
    do
            echo $element
done
```

And you execute the script using:

```
./myscript.ksh "my element"
```

The expected output should be:

```
my element
```

but the whitespace is treated as a separator for each argument, obtaining:

```
my
element
```

How should I escape the whitespace?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must either quote the `$@`, or use nothing:

```
for element in "$@"
```

or

```
for element
```

will both work.

Answer (score 5):

You must enclose `$@`, see [Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters), in double quotes:

> ($@) Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one.
> ...
> When the expansion occurs within double quotes, and word splitting
> is performed, each parameter expands to a separate word. That is,
> "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" ….

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

for element in "$@"
do
    echo $element
done
```

You can get the same output by omitting `in "$@"` ([Looping Constructs, for](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-for)) altogether:

> If ‘in words’ is not present, the for command executes the commands
> once for each positional parameter that is set, as if ‘in "$@"’ had
> been specified

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

for element
do
    echo $element
done
```